# ANR triggered by thread waiting for a binder transaction MobileAds.initialize()

Tags: android, admob, crashlytics, mobileads

My app is crashing in so some devices and I have received this crash report in Crashlytics. Below is the crash report stack

**com.pn.namewallpaper.App.onCreate
ANR triggered by thread waiting for a binder transaction**

```
main (native):tid=1 systid=29049 
#00 pc 0x4b50c libc.so (syscall + 28)
#01 pc 0x1b07a4 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 148)
#02 pc 0x673d78 libart.so (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*) + 480)
#03 pc 0x673b54 libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int, art::Thread*) + 28)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native method)
       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:540)
       at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:730)
       at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.getStringForUser(Settings.java:2769)
       at android.provider.Settings$System.getStringForUser(Settings.java:3204)
       at android.provider.Settings$System.getIntForUser(Settings.java:3303)
       at android.provider.Settings$System.getInt(Settings.java:3297)
       at org.chromium.ui.accessibility.AccessibilityState.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:193)
       at org.chromium.ui.accessibility.AccessibilityState.registerObservers(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:87)
       at J.N.M1Y_XVCN(Native method)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:10)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.f(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:67)
       at E9.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:111)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at org.chromium.base.task.PostTask.d(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:11)
       at org.chromium.android_webview.AwBrowserProcess.k(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:34)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.M.d(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:183)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.M.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:42)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.k(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:11)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-573519631:94)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:435)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:355)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:337)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:324)
       at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:314)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.r.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.v.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.k.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.q.run(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.c.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.d.execute(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ah.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:3)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.ah.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:5)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.js.function.n.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.e.b(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:20)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.e.a(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.az.i(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:8)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.bu.bN(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:34)
       at agb.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@231710101@231710100057.526733554.526733554:4)
       at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:1043)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzato.zzbh(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-base@@22.2.0:2)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzcm.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzej.zzz(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:4)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.client.zzej.zzn(zzej.java:23)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@22.2.0:3)
       at com.pn.namewallpaper.App.onCreate(App.kt:54)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1192)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6756)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:244)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1952)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7703)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:612)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:997)
```

Below is code snippet for my App.kt file

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    try {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            val process = getProcessName()
            if (packageName != process) {
                WebView.setDataDirectorySuffix(process)
                WebView(this)
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    try {
        MobileAds.initialize(this) { }

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            MobileAds.setRequestConfiguration(
                RequestConfiguration.Builder()
                    .setTestDeviceIds(listOf("E80042EF1278636536D6C76694C9515C")).build()
            )

        appOpenManager = AppOpenManager(this)

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```